# Jira query - show cards created between today and minus 14 days from today

Tags: jira, jql

I can't seem to find a solution for my query in jira. 
I wish to only show cards created between today and -14 days from today.

I am thinking along the lines of `created >= today(-14d) AND created <= today()`.

I can't seem to use today(-14d) in my version of Jira which is 6.1.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

You can use this JQL query:

```
created >= -14d AND created <= now()
```

See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching

Comment: I don't think you need the `AND created <= now()`, `created >= -14d` would always already match those

Answer (score 5):

Looks like jira returns result based on timestamp instead of date. So -1d is NOW minus 24 hrs..... ; I experienced that results were not showing all records of previous day as well as the outcome changed when time elapsed during the day.

Found a solution by using: 
created  >= startOfDay(-1)